# mysql query select by tag

Tags: mysql, select

I have a database with 3 tables with content and i need to get content out of it based on a query of tags.

The tables look like this:

```
nv_entries:
id - title - year - etc..

nv_tags:
id - entrieid - tag

nv_images:
id - entrieid - source
```

Let's say i want all entries that have the tag 'rousseau' and both 'fuzz' in it.
After that the images should join aswell where entrieid = entrieid.

This can probably done with one query but i have no idea how.

```
$query = "SELECT * from nv_entries WHERE ???
```

please help

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a one to many relationship between entries and tags, you have to use a pivot table on the tags table.  Simply saying where tag = 'x" and tag = 'y" won't work because the engine looks at this on a row by row basis so tag can't have both values at the same time.  So basically you pivot, assigning flags to each entry that state whether that entry has been seen to have the tag value you're looking for.

```
SELECT * 
FROM nv_entries entries 
JOIN (
    SELECT entrieid, 
           COUNT(CASE WHEN (tag = 'rousseau') THEN 1 ELSE null END) has_rousseau,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN (tag = 'fuzz') THEN 1 ELSE null END) has_fuzz
    FROM nv_tags
    GROUP BY entrieid
    HAVING has_rousseau != 0 and has_fuzz != 0
    ) tags ON (entries.id = tags.entrieid)
JOIN nv_images images ON (tags.entrieid = images.entrieid);
```

Comment: this is extreme difficult for if other tags are used, or 3 tags/4tags are used. Any solution for that?

Comment: what about getting entries double and look at php how many times a entrie is loaded, if it's equal to the amount of tags then keep it?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm clear on what you're stating in your comment about "getting entries double".  As far as difficulty, you can make the query more generic and build the SQL dynamically to provide the correct number of values you're searching for.  (use bind variables though for passing in the actual values)

Comment: let's say i have 2 tags.
First i get all entries with the first tag, then i get all entries with the 2nd tag. Then keep all the entries that are double. This meight be not the cleanest way but i need to finish it today.

Comment: is this correct to get the content from one tag?
`SELECT * 
FROM nv_entries entries 
JOIN (
    SELECT entrieid          
    FROM nv_tags WHERE tag = '$tag'
    GROUP BY entrieid
    ) tags on (entries.id = tags.entrieid)
join nv_images images on (tags.entrieid = images.entrieid);`

Comment: For one entry you could just do: SELECT * 
FROM nv_entries entries 
JOIN nv_tags tags on (entries.id = tags.entrieid)
join nv_images images on (tags.entrieid = images.entrieid)
WHERE tags.tag = 'blah';

Comment: I tested and i believe your close, no error shows up but no content either.
`$query = "SELECT * FROM nv_entries entries JOIN nv_tags tags on (entries.id = tags.entrie_id) join nv_images images on (tags.entrie_id = images.entrie_id) WHERE tags.tag = '$tag'";`
small mistake maybe?

Comment: I have entrie_id in my SQL where you're table is entrieid though this should have given an error.  Also, if not all entries have an image, you'll need to make the join on nv_images a left outer join.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM
nv_entries entries
INNER JOIN nv_tags tags ON  tags.entrieid = entries.id
INNER JOIN nv_images imgs ON imgs.entrieid = entries.id
WHERE tags.tag IN('rousseau','fuzz')
```

but this will extract all data from three tables.
specify your tags relative to the table to avoid redundant tags as entrieid.

Comment: This isn't going to work.  The tags.tag can't equal rousseau and fuzz at the same time. The SQL is processed a row at a time.

Comment: @RC: You are right!
Please correct this issue. Tell if this work?? IF not worked, then use tags.tag IN('rousseau','fuzz').

PS:
One user posted an answer with the same IN condition but I said he was wrong and he removed the answer. I am sorry for him. You may include your answer.

Comment: what if more tags are used (or just 1)?